# Canonical Form Question

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a quick question about some Boolean algebra.

The problem is:

> F (A, B, C) = A + B

And I want to expand it into canonical-sum form. The problem is there is no 'C' so I am unclear on how to do it. Normally, I would find the min-term and go from there, however, the min-term has C in it. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$A+B=A(B+\bar B)(C+\bar C)+B(A+\bar A)(C+\bar C)$$
Expand this expression, get rid of duplicates and you are done.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: @Cyberboy1551 You are welcome.

Comment: @Cyberboy1551 You can accept my answer by clicking the check mark to the left.